# add get_post tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Generally SE is smart about avoiding silly duplicate tags (ie: post vs. posts). IN this case, I wanted to create a tag for get_post, referring to the `get_post()` function, which is different indeed from `get_posts()`, so the disambiguation made sense to me. Any thoughts?

[The post in which this issue was originally raised](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29749/elegant-way-to-include-only-published-posts-with-get-objects-in-term).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do now prevent users from creating new tags that differ only by a dash or a plural.  There's no need to have [tagsynonyms] when we already have [tag-synonyms], for example.

This check does not apply to a moderator, so raising this issue on meta so that one of the moderators can edit the post is correct.  However, a link to the question that needs to be edited would help. (:

Comment: DOH! Of course. Updated.

Comment: I edited the post to create the`get-post` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rebecca!

Answer (score 0):

SE is not smart, hard moderator work at creating [tag synonyms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is smart. :)

What exactly is your problem with creating that tag? You seem to have sufficient reputation for that.

Comment: SE doesn't let me create the tag because it sees that a tag called get-posts (plural) already exists and the (limited) intelligence prevents creating what it considers a "duplicate" tag and suggests I post a discussion or support question on Meta. Which this is. :)

Comment: @Tom then this needs someone from higher up looking at it, I was not aware of such tag filtering and don't think I can influence it...

Comment: This is a new-ish feature.  I added [an answer](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/746/add-get-post-tag/748#748) to clarify.

Comment: I looked at all the tag synonyms you created. Wow, you weren't kidding: that IS a lot of work! Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Tom you are welcome :) See this question http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/565/tag-analyzer-snippet if you want to play with tags via SE API and point out synonyms that should be created